# Excel Interop - How to change named range

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a template excel file that I fill data into from SQL Server OLEDB connector. The file contains some pivot tables that refer to the dataset being filled in by the database.

Currently what I do is that I select all rows in sheet by using "Data!$A:$K" range. This brings a problem with blank values being shown in the pivot table.

What I wanted to do is to create a named table over the dataset and refer the pivot tables to that (plus I gain some other advantages that names tables bring).

The number of rows is naturally not set so I wanted to find a way to set the named range scope to the actual values only.

I'm using Excel Interop and C# for that and I can't find a way to change the range. I only got as far as:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("Transactions");
```

Which selects the named range. But how do I change which cells belong to it?

Or is there perhaps a better solution I should pursue?

**EDIT**

Dynamic ranges are the answer!

I solved this thanks to @TimWilliams reply:

"Use a dynamic range in your template: http://ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm"

I feel the dynamic ranges are better described here: http://www.contextures.com/xlpivot01.html

I encountered a slight issue that I couldn't use the range in pivot table because it demanded it needs at least 2 rows to operate - the template file only has column headings. I added a random string to 1st cell of 2nd row and pivot table accepted that.

Afterwards I had to remove that row using c# code.

Thank you guys for help.

Comment: Use a dynamic range in your template: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Answer (score 5):

By doing the following, you will create a named range (Transactions) on the oSheet staring at cell A1 and finising at cell C3

```
Range namedRange= oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[3, 3]];
namedRange.Name = "Transactions";
```

If the name already exist in the workbook it will be replace, if not it will be created.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got an error: "A table with that name already exists. Select a different name."

Answer (score 3):

It's probably too late for WilliF but I came across the same issue and this worked:

```
oRng = oSheet.get_Range("Transactions");

Range namedRange = oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[3, 3]];
namedRange.Name = "Transactions";
```

From [here](http://pastebin.com/YqYaieV8)

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to identify the occupied range of cells in the sheet.  Then assign it a name.  You can use the [`UsedRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of the worksheet to obtain this, and there are a few other methods as well.

[Programmatically getting the last filled excel row using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674573/programmatically-getting-the-last-filled-excel-row-using-c-sharp)

[How to get the range of occupied cells in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284388/how-to-get-the-range-of-occupied-cells-in-excel-sheet)

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to change a range of cells for named range that already exist.

Comment: @WilliF Delete and re-create the range.  Can't remember the API call that does this off the top of my head, but google knows all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a named range by:

```
var oRng = oSheet.get_Range("Transactions");
```

Then you can move or resize it using `Range.get_Offset(*RowOffset*, *ColumnOffset*)` or `Range.get_Resize(*RowSize*, *ColumnSize*)`. Also you can use `Offset[]` and `Resize[]`:

```
var newRange = oRng.Offset[-1,3].Resize[2,4];
```

Then you can save it as named range this way:

```
oSheet.Names.Add("Transactions", newRange);
```

PS: `newRange.Name = "Transactions"` didn't work for me.