# Clear filter from Table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a macro that replaces data in a table in Excel, when the data might initially be filtered.

The code should remove the filter first, then run the rest of the code.

I tried the "Autofilter" command, but then the normal filter option on the table's range weren't visible, and I had to manually create the filter option again (not a big deal to me, but other people use this file).

Is there a way to clear the filter WITHOUT removing filters from the table?

Comment: show relevant code for more precise help please

Comment: The answer here should work to showalldata in a table.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226045/showalldata-method-of-worksheet-class-failed

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For a Table, you can simply use the `ShowAllData` method of its `Autofilter` object:

```
activesheet.listobjects(1).autofilter.showalldata
```

Note this won't error even if there is no filter currently applied.

Comment: When unfiltering tables to this do the following `activesheet.listobjects("Table Name").AutoFilter.ShowAllData` That fixed the issue I had

Answer (score 8):

This expands on the answer from @Rory (the go-to-answer I look up every time I can't remember the syntax).  It avoids errors that occur when the table doesn't contain an auto-filter.

The section `If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing` checks for the AutoFilter object property of the ListObject (table).  If it `Is Nothing` then that table had it's auto-filter removed.

```
With Activesheet.Listobjects(1)
    If not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Guys use this "Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter = False" and please note if already filter applied it will remove filter on the other hand if filter not applied before it will apply the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I am finding that the "...ClearAllData" method fails.

Sneaky - not hugely elegant solution - that works by field (so cumbersome if you need to do the whole table), but easy if you just have one field (e.g. field 2 in my example) is to use the wildcard:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=*"
```

Comment: Sorry - better: no "Criteria..." required.

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Or

```
Cells.AutoFilter
```

Comment: I could have added some error handling checks but does your link above not mention those methods?

Comment: The codes you provided will not work in a filtered table, they will work in a filtered sheet, but that is not the question.

Comment: Apologies, the Cells one errors but the ShowAllData one works

Comment: The problem is that it seems to clear the default filtering option on the table headers, which is a problem for a shared sheet.