# VBA code sometimes work but sometimes doesn't on AutoFilter line in Table formatted WorkSheet

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, runtime-error

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
.
.

Set ws1 = Sheet1
ws1.Activate 'I'd like to see the sheet that's why I activate it. It's not a bad practice.
ws1.Columns.Hidden = False
ws1.Rows.Hidden = False
ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
.
.
```

I have this CommandButton2 in another sheet and whenever I click, It firstly clear all filters from Sheet1, then Unhidden any column or row if exist.

I tried lots of different variations to be able to follow the issue. I did some filtering on 2-3 or 4 columns and then hided some rows and columns at the same time. But unfortunately I couldn't find the reason.

> - Sometimes my code works perfectly.

I mean, It unhidden every hidden row and column and then clear all filters from columns.

> - Interestingly sometimes code partly works.

Sometimes my code works, but doesn't unhide hidden rows/columns and doesn't clear filters. So it seems like it's technically working but not in functionality.

> - Sometimes it gives an Runtime 91 error.

Sometimes it totally doesn't work and gives a `Runtime 91 Object variable or With Block variable not set`

> - Sometimes it starts to work after trying to run code for 2-3-4 times.

If I consistently click my CommandButton2 after first error, and change the sheets in the meantime and coming back to CommandButton2's sheet and click the button again sometimes solve the problem.

I actually have a solution. Instead of `ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` with below code the problem is disappearing. But I wonder what do I miss on the first one? What would be the reason why it occurs error on `ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData`? Because I use it somewhere else without any problem.

```
ws1.Select
If (ws1.AutoFilterMode And ws1.FilterMode) Or ws1.FilterMode Then
ws1.ShowAllData
End If
```

Comment: How could I recreate the error? When you debug does it indicate that code crashed in the part you provided?

Comment: It might be that sometimes you don't have autofiltering on your sheet, then `ws1.AutoFilter` would return `Nothing`, which could be the reason for error. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-autofilter-property-excel for reference. Just investigated: created autofilter on the sheet. Error didn't occur.

Comment: Yes Michał, it debugs `ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` line. And no, having no autofilter was one of my combinations. And actually `.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` shouldn't create that error this is different than just `.AutoFilter`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn And recreating error is the main problem. As I explained, I tried to recreate the error with many different combinations, but one that gives an error doesn't give an error on my next attempt.

Comment: Are you using tables?

Comment: Yes Vegard, ws1 sheet has a table and filters are for this table, what do you think?

Comment: _But I wonder what do I miss on the first one?_  You missed `ws1.FilterMode`.  This is TRUE if any rows are hidden as a result of a filter - you don't need to check `AutoFilterMode`.  If `FilterMode` is True then  you have a filter and it's filtering.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa168763(v=office.11).aspx  Also `ws1.Rows.Hidden = False` won't unhide filtered rows.

Comment: Hi Darren, thank you for your interest. But the problem was occuring because of my sheet was in Table form. So adding `ListObject(1)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the filters are set in a table** (or several tables, but you'll need code modification), as you indicated in the comments, [try this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33208645/4604845)

```
ws1.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

[or this one:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27529109/4604845)

```
ws1.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = False
ws1.ListObjects(1).ShowAutoFilter = True
```

Note that if you have several `ListObject`s in your sheet, you'll have to specify manually which one you want - either by the index, as shown above, by name, or by iteration.

By name:

```
ws1.ListObjects("Table1")
```

By iteration:

```
For Each tbl In ws1.ListObjects
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Next tbl
```

Lastly, if you're going to reference the `ListObject` more than once, like if you want to work on the table more extensively, I highly recommend setting a variable for it, like this:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects(1)
tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

Working with `ListObject` in this way is [very powerful](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

Comment: Now my sheet has some filters active and have some hidden rows/columns, and AutoFilterMode seems already false.
And even if I write `Ws1.Cells.Autofilter` now it gives `Runtime 1004, AutoFilter method of range class failed` error.

Comment: Try replacing `ws1.Cells.AutoFilter` with `ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData`.

Comment: That one actually what I had in my question, so I already try to run this one. And actually I have a solution instead of this one but I am trying to understand why it does act strange when I use `ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn The idea was to turn autofilter off and on again. I am unsure if `AutoFilter.ShowAllData` would re-engage it correctly?

Comment: @Mertinc Added a table-specific variant to the answer. I'm not sure, but perhaps the filters being in the `ListObject` scope and not the `Worksheet` scope is what causes the behavior you have seen.

Comment: Hey Vegard that's it! Thank you for your interest, I didn't know that there should be a different approach for Tables. So adding `ListObjects(1)` to my `ws1.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` code solved the problem. So `ws1.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData` but all the others are useless honestly:) can you please edit your answer according to these for any future reference.

Comment: I can, but you have to edit your question to include that you are filtering tables. Otherwise my answer will seem off-topic to anyone who doesn't dig through the comments :)