# Remove filters from ALL Excel Tables VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating some Excel Add-ins to complete some basic tasks for our users. We have a spreadsheet that is provided to our users for each of our projects. They use these spreadsheets to make changes to configurable items prior to us processing a conversion to an SQL database. When they complete the spreadsheet, often times they forget to unhide rows, columns, and/or remove filters. I would like to create a macro that can be run to Unhide Rows/Columns from each worksheet and to clear filters from each ListObject. Here is the code I was attempting to use:

```
Sub RemoveFiltersUnhide()
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).AutoFilterMode = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Rows.Hidden = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Columns.Hidden = False
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code works to Unhide Rows/Columns on each sheet, but it does not clear filters. Since each provided workbook will be different and will not contain the same worksheets or listobjects, I do not know how to go about looping through each table. Anyone have any thoughts on how I can approach this?

---

Working VBA:

```
Sub RemoveFiltersUnhide()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Rows.Hidden = False
        ws.Columns.Hidden = False

        For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
            lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to clear filters from sheets, [try this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21761226/8060864) For tables (ListObjects), [try this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33208645/8060864)

Comment: Thank you. I've viewed these previously. Since my tables(listobjects) will differ depending on the project, this does not work for me.

Comment: So you need to loop through all the ListObjects in all the worksheets in a workbook?

Comment: Correct. I need to loop through all possible ListObjects and clear filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the syntax provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33208645/8060864) is correct, the following should work.

```
Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet, List As Excel.ListObject

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each List In Sheet.ListObjects
        List.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, Hao! I tweaked it slightly and it works perfectly.

Comment: You should use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables. Also `ListObject` is a reserved word and therefore not allowed as a variable name! Use something else like `MyListObject` as variable name instead to avoid conflicts with reserved words.

Comment: @Peh Noted. Modified my answer to include variable declarations. Although it is worth noting that [the return value for a For Each statement's control variable will always be a `Variant` or generic `Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/for-each-control-variable-must-be-variant-or-object), so I'm not sure if there's an advantage here.

Comment: @HaoZhang if you do a `Debug.Print TypeName(Sheet)` within your `For Each` loop you will see that it is **not** returning a *generic* object but a defined *worksheet* object. Nevertheless it is always a good practice to declare all variables even if they are variants.

Comment: @Peh I guess it only applies to variants. If you tried to Dim the control variable as other primitive types, it will give you a compile error.

Comment: @HaoZhang this applies to all objects.

Comment: @Peh I was talking about how declaring the control variable as a non-variant / non-generic object would cause a compilation error, but apparently it only applies to the primitive data types as it seems to work fine with different classes of objects. You can't, for example, Dim the control variable as a string, but you can Dim it specifically as a Workbook object.

Comment: @HaoZhang yes that's what I said it applies to objects, but a string is not an object there you would need a variant (apparently we are talking about the same thing).

Answer (score 3):

The code would be like this.

```
Sub RemoveFiltersUnhide()

Dim i As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Ws In Worksheets
    With Ws
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
        .Rows.Hidden = False
        .Columns.Hidden = False

    End With
Next Ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `FilterMode` should be `.FilterMode`. Remember `Option Explicit` is your friend.