# Last cell (column and row) of a Excel range object in C#

Tags: c#

```
Dim Lrow,LColumn as Long
Sheet1.Activate
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
LRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
End If
```

Can someone help to convert this vba code to C# getting lastrow and lastcolumn in a worksheet.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430418/get-the-last-cell-column-row-of-a-excel-range-object

Comment: Link provided will return used range not the actual range. Used range could contain many empty rows and columns in a range.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help, but still we need to focus on one column/row to get the last cell.  If you don't known which column to focus because data in the spreadsheet are uneven. If I guess for one column to get Last Row that would be wrong.  Therefore the above vba code works a specialist and can never go wrong finding last column and last row.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5fa24ca9-2949-4442-b0f1-742e941cfe5a/how-to-get-the-last-cell-on-a-sheet-in-c-like-endxlup-in-excel-vba?forum=exceldev

or
Try this to get last row and last column of excel sheet,

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;           

   // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
   // store its reference to worksheet
   worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

   int rowcount = worksheet.Rows.Count;
   int colcount = worksheet.Columns.Count;
```

Comment: This function gives rowcount=1048576 and colcount=16384 meaning all cells in a worksheet not the last row or last column of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This also has pitfalls. Read:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110873/excel-application-cells-specialcellsxlcelltypelastcell-returning-bottom-of-wor)

Comment: try http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/find-last-cell-value-particular-column-26162.aspx

Comment: This link is again focus on a column to get last row.

Comment: After having lots of research and with my long experience with excel and vba. I found the only solution to find accurate results.  Therefore, I would like to convert this in to C# code.

Comment: oh congrats.post the answer you tried that may help others.

Comment: The vba code in my question is the only perfect solution but unfortunately I couldn't be able to convert into C# code.