# how to get last filled row from excel sheet in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I want to know that how to get the last filled row from excel sheet.
I have used  `FullRow = worksheet.Rows.Count;`
But it returns all rows from the excel sheet.

Comment: see this question: [How to determine last used row/column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920). It's about excel-vba, but can give you the idea how to do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically getting the last filled excel row using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674573/programmatically-getting-the-last-filled-excel-row-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @mehow Thanks for the suggestion. Deleted. Getting used to SO :)

Comment: no problem @LakshmiNarayanan. I am glad you're following the rules most of people tend to start fights etc...

Comment: Thanks every one to give ur tym.Previously the same code(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674573/programmatically-getting-the-last-filled-excel-row-using-c-sharp) was not working for me.so i again posted here. But now luck by chance it worked. :)