# How to get excel range topleft and bottomright cell in en Excel worksheet.

Tags: excel, python-2.7, ironpython, worksheet

I would like to find the topleft cell and bottomright  cell  in an Excel worksheet range, which is a bounding box of all occupied cells in the sheet, from ironpython 2.7.5 on win 7.

My code:

```
 from Microsoft.Office.Interop import Excel
 from System import Type

 excel = Excel.ApplicationClass()
 workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFilename, False, True)
 allWorksheets = workbook.WorkSheets
 for aWorkSheet in allWorksheets:
      last = aWs.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
      range = excel.get_Range("A1", last);
      print "a worksheet range is " + str(range)
```

I need to find the topleft cell and bottomright  cell  in the "range"
The links at

[Programmatically getting the last filled excel row using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674573/programmatically-getting-the-last-filled-excel-row-using-c-sharp)

[How to get the range of occupied cells in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284388/how-to-get-the-range-of-occupied-cells-in-excel-sheet)

Cannot help me.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the range with `.Value` like this:

```
 ws.Range("A3:B4").Value = "A3:B4"
```

As shown on line of 11 of the [ranges_and_offsets.py](https://github.com/pythonexcels/examples/blob/28a171faaf65e9924488dc89d3065ac354af0b02/ranges_and_offsets.py) example.

Comment: thanks, but I need to knwo the topleft corner cell address and the bottomright corner cell address of the range.

Comment: in the range listed in my example `A3` is top left and `B4` is bottom right