# Getting the last filled excel row using C# per specific column

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

Getting the last Excel row in a given worksheet has lots of [nice answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674573/programmatically-getting-the-last-filled-excel-row-using-c-sharp).
However, sometimes all we need is the last row of a given column and not of the whole spreadsheet.

I thought of a solution, which seems a bit slow:

- find the last row in Excel for all columns;
- start looping from there to 1, in the specific column, trying to find the first cell which is not empty. This is the result;
- for empty first row and only first row in a given column, always return 1;

This is the implementation:

---

```
namespace ExcelTest
{
    using System;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public class Startup
    {
        const string filePath = @"C:\Users\gropc\Desktop\Sample.xlsx";

        static void Main()
        {
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application { Visible = true, EnableAnimations = false };
            Excel.Workbook wkb = Open(excel, filePath);

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet wks in wkb.Worksheets)
            {
                int lastRowA = LastRowPerColumn(1, wks);
                int lastRowB  = LastRowPerColumn(2, wks);
                int lastRowC = LastRowPerColumn(3, wks);
                Console.WriteLine($"{lastRowA} - {lastRowB} - {lastRowC}");
            }

            wkb.Close(true);
            excel.Quit();
        }

        static int LastRowPerColumn(int column, Excel.Worksheet wks)
        {
            int lastRow = LastRowTotal(wks);
            while (((wks.Cells[lastRow, column]).Text == "") && (lastRow != 1))
            {
                lastRow--;
            }
            return lastRow;
        }

        static int LastRowTotal(Excel.Worksheet wks)
        {
            Excel.Range lastCell = wks.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            return lastCell.Row;
        }

        static Excel.Workbook Open(Excel.Application excelInstance,
            string fileName, bool readOnly = false,
            bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
        {
            return excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(fileName, updateLinks, readOnly);
        }
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

- `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`;
- `const string filePath = @"C:\Users\gropc\Desktop\Sample.xlsx";`

**Question:**

Any ideas to avoid the looping? In [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) the solution is quite charming in 1 line:

`lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row`

Anything similar for the C# Excel Interop?

Comment: How about writing a query? Besides, you know the column/s and everything else you need; throw this in the where clause of a query you can perform.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ - this probably seems like a faster way than looping. Can you implement it?